# Get public ip of router

Tags: c#, dns, ip

I there a way to determine the IP address WITHOUT resorting to a remote server to validate a web request.  Seems like if you can trace-route you could get all ip's in a chain... Unsure how to validate that.

If it's not possible, it does make sense that it could not be.  It makes sense that you would want Multiple remote endpoints to validate your ip, in case one is compromised.

Comment: Doesn't traceroute force you to resort to a remote server as well?

Comment: Doh! yes totally slipped.

Answer (score 0):

`traceroute` won't even help. You'd need a traceroute *from* somewhere out there on the Internet *toward* you to get the public IP address of a NAT that you are behind.

There is no general way to ask a NAT router what public IP address it will use for connections that you originate. In general there could even be more than one (e.g. load balanced WAN connections).